# Css does not change text color in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I'm learning to use css external style. The content is just a sentence and css will change the sentence color to red. I tried it on Codepend.io and IE and it works fine. But in Opera, the sentence color doesn't turn red. I'm using Opera 37.0.2178.43. So how can I make Opera show the text color?

```css
p {color:red;}
```

```html
<html lang="vi">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Embedding CSS in External Styles</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the pictures
[image]

Comment: Do you have the file `style.css` in the same location as of the HTML ?

Comment: @Pugazh yes, I put them in the same folder

Comment: Do you have `p{color: red;}` in your `style.css` ?

Comment: I just ran the snippet in Opera `37.0.2178.43`. I works fine. Are you sure you don't just overwrite it somewhere else?

Comment: @ Manfred Radlwimmer: I put the page.html and style.css in the same folder called Web. The sentence is red in IE so I don't think location is the problem.

Comment: @Pugazh: Yes, I put them in there.

Comment: It seems a typographycal error or something similar. Impossible to reproduce. Your snippet works fine. All you can try in external sites (jsfiddle, codepen, etc) works perfectly. It's the simplest CSS in the world and it works in all browsers. So this should be closed as offtopic, at least if you can't reproduce the problem to show it us.

Comment: @stuartd: I tried refresh, close the tab and open the page.html again, close the Opera and open it again. Non of them works

Comment: Try to inspect element in console to see which styles are applied to the element and why your color property is not working.

Comment: @OliverH: In the Elements window, there are html codes. I click on the Sources tag, style.css and change the color to blue, and the sentence becomes blue, I undo and the sentence becomes red. I refresh the page and the sentence turns back to black, the code in css file becomes Chinese symbols.

Comment: That's your encoding. You are writing code in another charset than UTF-8, sure. Probably ISO-8859-1 (windows), or some CJK encoding.  Try to write your CSS in the windows notepad (not notepad++), from the scratch.

Comment: There is definitely problem with your PC or Opera. I've checked in mine with same code and got expected result. Try to update your opera or reinstall it and check.

Comment: can be you have custom stylesheets in opera, unsupported default encoding, invalid characters that looks like english. upload all those file somewhere else so we can take a look

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude I delete the "lang" and "charset" but they are still chinese after refreshing. By the way, how can I close this topic? By clicking delete?

Comment: No needed to remove lang and charset attributes, try to open Notepad (without ++), write the rule (don't copy&paste), save with `style.css` name and test it in the browser. It's for sure a problem with your encoding.

Comment: Oh, I rewrite everything (html and css) on notepad, saving it in ANSI Encoding and it works. The sentence turns red now. Thank you @ Marcos Pérez Gude. I remember to set the Encoding to Unicode last time because the paragraph was written in Vietnamese. So what if I want to write Vietnamese in paragraph next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It's because I set the Encoding of html file to Unicode. Thanks @Marcos Pérez Gude